# Error on Expo - Failed to load all assets

Tags: ios, reactjs, continuous-integration, gitlab, expo

For some reason when first starting my app with the command `expo r -ci --no-dev` I receive the `Failed to load all assets error`.

[Image of the received error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcvv4.png)

If I go and manually reload the app it fixes the problem but my goal is to not have any interaction with my app.

I am using `expo-cli@4.0.11` version and booting my app through `gitlab ci`.

Comment: Any news on this issue? Tks!

Comment: Did you guys manage to find a solution? I'm stuck on this error