# Expo (React Native) Failed to load all assets error

Tags: react-native, expo

I randomly see `expo start -ci --no-dev` fail with `Failed to load all assets`.

[image: Failed to load all assets error]

I cleaned up my TS errors and its passing with no errors.
I have been debugging this for three days now and getting nowhere. The error gives no clue as to what is failing. "Extra Info" is blank. Device log shows nothing.
To make things worse, I gradually add packages and functions into my monorepo, and at some point the error appears. So I'm thinking - ok, so the error is with this file. Commenting it out, trying again to make sure - yes it now works. Uncommenting it to make sure it was the problem - No. It doesn't fail. It works.

Seems like I am not alone: [Error on Expo - Failed to load all assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65289831/error-on-expo-failed-to-load-all-assets)

Comment: Could you finally find the solution for your issue? Same here. Tks!

Comment: I totally forgot about this. Honestly, I switched to working with custom dev clients and I don't remember the last time I saw this error.

Comment: Ok Tks anyway Ben! If I manage to solve it in the future I'll post the answer in this post so it can help others.

Comment: Did you guys manage to find a solution? I'm stuck on this error